# How to add a node with child properties and set values to them?

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I have built a OPC UA server from the  OPCFoundation example - https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard

Also compiled my own model with - 
https://github.com/Pro/UA-ModelCompiler/tree/eebf9988940a789a4f36cbef8c5bd6340f1b2f42

In the examples they have the generated files in folders and then custom made classes for NodeManger, State and so on.

I have successfully loaded the generated .uanodes file, with some example nodes in it. But I cannot create those nodes by code from server side. When testing I am doing it in the function - LoadPredefinedNodes(ISystemContext context).

My structure should be a node below Objects called "Tags", in that node I want to dynamically add nodes and set their properties when the server is running.

I am using Integration Object´s OPC UA Client when testing.

The strucure looks correct, for example:
Objects => Tags => MyTestTag (Properties: Name, Description, Value)

The first two properties are added correctly from the model file definition

```xml
    <!-- ### Object Types ###-->

    <!-- BaseType -->
    <ObjectType SymbolicName="TAG:TagType" BaseType="ua:BaseObjectType" IsAbstract="true" SupportsEvents="true" AccessLevel="ReadWrite">
        <Description>Base type for all tags</Description>
        <Children>
            <Property SymbolicName="TAG:Name" DataType="ua:String" ValueRank="Scalar" ModellingRule="Mandatory" AccessLevel="ReadWrite">
                <Description>Name of the tag</Description>
            </Property>
            <Property SymbolicName="TAG:Description" DataType="ua:String" ValueRank="Scalar" ModellingRule="Optional" AccessLevel="ReadWrite">
                <Description>Description of the tag</Description>
            </Property>
        </Children>
    </ObjectType>

    <!-- ### Objects ###-->
    <Object SymbolicName="TAG:Tags" TypeDefinition="ua:BaseObjectType">
        <Description>Contains all instances of tags</Description>
        <References>
            <Reference IsInverse="true">
                <ReferenceType>ua:Organizes</ReferenceType>
                <TargetId>ua:ObjectsFolder</TargetId>
            </Reference>
        </References>
    </Object>
```

The third is the Property I try to define from code on server side. I got the Value property added, but I cannot figure out how to write it´s value.

```cs
        protected override NodeStateCollection LoadPredefinedNodes(ISystemContext context)
        {
            NodeStateCollection predefinedNodes = new NodeStateCollection();
            predefinedNodes.LoadFromBinaryResource(context, "Opc.Ua.ValmetData.Tag.Tag.PredefinedNodes.uanodes", this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly, true);

            // The defined ObjectType in the model
            NodeState tageTypeNode = predefinedNodes.Find(x => x.SymbolicName == "TagType");

            // List node to add the tag to
            NodeState tagsNode = predefinedNodes.Find(x => x.SymbolicName == "Tags");

            ushort namespaceIndex = Server.NamespaceUris.GetIndexOrAppend(Namespaces.Tag);


            TagState tagNode = new TagState(tagsNode);
            tagNode.SymbolicName = "MyTestTag";
            tagNode.ClearChangeMasks(context, true);            

            PropertyState ps = new PropertyState(tagNode);
            ps.ClearChangeMasks(context, true);
            ps.NodeId = new NodeId();
            ps.Description = "This is a description";
            ps.TypeDefinitionId = tageTypeNode.NodeId;
            ps.NumericId = 66;
            //  ps.NodeClass = NodeClass.Variable;
            ps.ReferenceTypeId = ReferenceTypeIds.HasProperty;
            ps.BrowseName = new QualifiedName("Value", NamespaceIndex);
            ps.DisplayName = ps.BrowseName.Name;
            ps.DataType = (uint)BuiltInType.Int32;
            // ps.UserAccessLevel = AccessLevels.CurrentReadOrWrite;
            // ps.AccessLevel = AccessLevels.CurrentReadOrWrite;
            ps.Value = 66;

            tagNode.AddChild(ps);

            // assign
            tagNode.Create(
                SystemContext,
                new NodeId(tagNode.SymbolicName, namespaceIndex),
                new QualifiedName(tagNode.SymbolicName, namespaceIndex),
                null,
                true);

            tagsNode.AddChild(tagNode);

            return predefinedNodes;

}
```

From this code a node named MyTestTag is added in the Tags node. Properties "Name" and "Description" is added from the model. And the "Value" property is added by code. However, I cannot set the value for non of those properties.

When clicking on the property MyTestTag.Value in the client the error "Nullable object must have a value" is printed.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but this may help you in the future:
I created a PR which also adds a docker container to the UA-ModelCompiler. This has the advantage that you can just use the container to compile your model, instead of first compiling the ua-modelcompiler executable.

https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-ModelCompiler/pull/36

Comment: Thanks for the comment anyway. I will check it out later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was the nodeId. I changed

```cs
ps.NodeId = new NodeId();
// to
ps.NodeId = new NodeId(Guid.NewGuid(), NamespaceIndex);
```

Then it did show up in the node tree.

Answer (score 0):

Examples from OPC-UA have code bits for updating variables, so I am not sure what there is a problem with it.  Assuming I am setting good value the code may look like this:

```
variable.Value = value;
variable.Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
variable.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Good;
variable.ClearChangeMasks(SystemContext, false);
```